# /testfor moving player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making another map and the theme is that the player must keep moving at all times. How would I test if a player is moving? I think you can do it with scoreboard, but I'm not sure. Please help me.

Comment: I'll look for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is to create a scoreboard objective

```
/scoreboard objectives add Walking stat.walkOneCm Walking
```

You can show it on the side bar by using this command:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Walking
```

**Do these next steps on a 20Hz fill clock:**

You want to set the score of a player to 15 if it goes higher...

```
/execute @p[score_Walking_min=15] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @p Walking 10
```

Then take away 5 from the score every 20 ticks.

```
/scoreboard players remove @p Walking 5
```

If they stop moving the score will reach 0 very soon.

So you want to test if a player has a score of 0

```
/testfor @p[score_Walking_min=-100,score_Walking=0]
```

Feed that into a comparator and if the score goes below zero it will switch on...

Do whatever you want at that point!